# How can I handle switching to principal from mirror in mirroring?

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

Good day to all!

Can somebody tell me how can I handle an event, when mirror server becomes a principal? For example, I have:

- S1 - principal server
- S2 - mirror server
- W - witness server
- J1 - some job on S1
- J2 - some job on S2

And different situations with results that I need:

1. When S1 fails and W switches S2 to principal, J2 must be executed.
2. When I manually click 'Failover' button on S1, S2 becomes principal and J2 must be executed.
3. When I manually click 'Failover' button on S2 (after resolving problems on S1), S1 becomes principal and J1 must be executed.

I have found this article ([Database Mirroring Automating Failover for Multiple SQL Server Databases](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1564/database-mirroring-automating-failover-for-multiple-sql-server-databases/)), it works good in 1 and 3 case, but in 2 case it doesn't work. As I understand, the problem is that Manual Failover event occurs on S1 and S2 doesn't receive this event. So this method is not acceptable for me.

Question: How can I correctly handle switching a mirror database to principal for starting job or executing script?